# Nginx Autoindex Problems

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I'm trying to enable directory listing on one of my directories (domain.tld/mng). First I added this to my .conf file:

```
location = /mng {
    autoindex on;
}
```

It doesn't work so I have to do this:

```
location = /mng/ {
    autoindex on;
}
```

And it worked on domain.tld/mng/ but when I try to access my subdirectories like domain.tld/mng/01/ I get a 403 Forbidden error code. All the subdirectories have 755 permissions and is owned by the webserver (in my case, nginx:nginx). I wonder what could be wrong?

BTW, I'm using a wordpress website.

Comment: try using `location ~ /mng/.* {`, as `/mng/` matches only the last part of the url

Comment: It worked, thanks. I didn't know there was such a rule operator like that. I always end up on google searches with the "location =" rule when I try to search autoindex rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as posted by anonymous user, I just have to change the rule to this:

```
location ~ /mng/.* {
  autoindex on;
}
```

and it worked on all the subdirectories. Thank you.

Comment: You should also be able to use `location /mng/` (without an `=` or a `~`) instead of `location ~ /mng/.*` - I've used that approach before.